# Unable to restore specific directory from backup

Tags: 12.04, backup, restore, deja-dup

A couple of months ago, I backed up using deja dup. Since then I've reinstalled 12.04. Recently I tried to restore the Documents directory via 'Restore missing files', and the scan came up empty. Restoring everything from the backup works, but there's a giant chunk of useless information on it that I don't need. Is there any troubleshooting for this, or maybe a way to exclude a folder when I restore? Or any other way to do this? Backup is located on an external hard drive.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your system using the same host name / user name / ....  ???

Comment: No, different ones.

Answer (score 1):

`Déjà Dup` is a file back-up program that is quite easy to use and does what 95% of users need 99% of the time.

However, it is not the *most intelligent back-up solution* around.  As you re-installed your system and you have a different host name and user name, `Déjà Dup` cannot find the files the new user is looking for…

Therefore, you have to restore all files of a different host from a different user to a different location on the new host/user (very logical when you *know* about it). Then just copy the needed files over from the total restore to the new location (`~/Documents`) and delete the total restore.

*[Don't kill the messenger!](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/ne-tirez-pas-sur-le-pianiste.php)*  **;-)**

Comment: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**